# How to remove "confirm" of like button?

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-social-plugins

Our application never did like jacking. 
How to remove "confirm" of like button?

we test "FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create'.....".
'edge.create' caused that "confirm" of like button?

Comment: I have similar issue. Event is not firing even after confirmation. Have you found any solution?